# using javascript in .jsp file

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

So in eclipse when you generate a .jsp file it automatically includes the following top line:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
```

Is there a way to also include javascript code so that I can have some of the file written in java and some written in javascript?

Comment: Um, include an external JavaScript file? Do you realize that Java and JavaScript do not run at the same time?

Comment: But what if I need to use information from my java code? For example, I want to query a mysql database using java and then use the information I get there to do stuff with javascript

Comment: Learn about the page lifecycle.

Comment: That's a very vague statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is Yes, you can add the js in jsp. And this also has benefit. It helps you to use the values stored in request and session, because the js code which contains the jsp stuff in jsp will be compiled while the *.js file will not. And also you should keep in mind that you'd better put the js code in .js file not in jsp, so the browser doesn't need to load it repeatly and code seems more clear, also good for debug. Another answer has give you the example code to import js file, so I just ignore it.

Comment: So how exactly would I take the values stored in a request and use it in javascript code?

Comment: var userId='<%=(String)request.getAttribute("userId")%>'

Comment: @OQJF From when did JavaScript start to compile ? Its much better to have the JS code in separate .js file.

Comment: @A. K. your misunderstood what I mean, And surely I know that we'd better put js code in *.js, but for some special thing that we have to do this to directly contact with request or session. Nothing is the absolute, right?

Comment: @OQJF There is no limitation in putting JavaScript code in .js files. If you want to use a request attribute in JavaScript code, then retrieve the request attribute in JSP and pass the value to JavaScript function present in .js file.

Comment: @A.K How I retrieve request attribute in jsp without js? you want to use hidden, don't you think it's kind of redundant.

Comment: @OQJF Retrieve the request attribute in JSP like this ... 
`<%=(String)request.getAttribute("userId")%>` 
and pass this value to JavaScript function present in .js file like this ... 
`setUserId('<%=(String)request.getAttribute("userId")%>')`;
Note: The JS function `setUserId` is present in a .js file

Comment: When the application starts up, the js file is loaded and at that time, there is no userId in request, is this correct? If I just want to get a userId why I have to write a method in js? And also if I change the userId, How can I get the new userId since the js file has been loaded?

Answer (score 4):

Usually I include my JavaScript in JSP like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
```

This way I can minimize the js code and also cache it differently than JSP files in Tomcat.